# Bootstrap Navigation with more links.. Trying to find a solution with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a solution for my site navigation that consists with more links. After add more links it display in 2, 3 lines.please check the attached picture.[This is after add more links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfnwS.jpg)

in above picture, i added blue colored link and rest of all are default bootstrap navigation. I want to keep navigation in one line. if need to see more links, need to click that blue colored link (for testing purpose i set it to display none). also when re sizing the browser it also should keep in one line. 
 i wrote a jquery code and it works when browser decreasing the size. but when increasing the size it doesn't work by adding one by one again. Is there anyway to do this? Anybody can please help me to solve the issue or by giving an idea. 
Thanks

my codes,

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  
$(document).load($(window).bind("load", resThis));
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", resThis));

var tot=$('.nav').find('.chld').length;
var pos_top=$('.btn').position().top;


var marg=$('.container').width();

  function resThis(){
   
   for(var i=tot; i>=0; i--){
    if(pos_top>0){
     $( ".nav .chld:nth-child("+i+")" ).addClass('a');
    }
    pos_top=$('.btn').position().top;
   }
   
  }
    
    });
```

```css
.not{padding:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-radius:0%;}
.a{display:none !important;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
//ul{list-style:none;}
//ul li{float:left; padding:10px 30px; background-color:#C0B9B9; margin:10px; border-radius:10%;}
.not{padding:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-radius:0%;}
.a{display:none !important;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active chld"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="chld dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="float:right;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
        </a>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: How about "I want to create a horizontal navigation bar, implemented as a list of links in one line. If the list exceeds 1 line, the additional links are only supposed to be visible once the user clicks the more button (blue button in the screenshot). 
My current solution sort of works when the screen width decreases but not when it increases, here is the code"

Comment: Thank you gvijay. I wanted to explain more about this.

Answer (score 0):

it works as intended for me even in full-screen and resizing it to all kinds of width... cant replicate the error you are describing and showing.

Comment: it works when decreasing , but when increasing it wont work

Comment: it works for me perfectly when i **dont** click the blue button, but i dont understand why you want to use the blue button anyway. If you want to have the dropdown button in blue, why dont you just change its background color? seems much easier